# I want to write Java code in Jmeter to copy current date in a variable and use this variable in next request. Where should I write it?

Tags: automated-testing, java, jmeter

**This is my code:**

```
package dateTime;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class GetCurrentDateTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
       String date = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd").format(localDate);
        log.info("The date is "+date);
vars.put("currentDate",date);

    }

}
```

I tried above code in *beanshell*, *JSR223* pre-processor or post processor but not able to use it further.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) as the language you can simplify your code to this one-liner:

```
vars.put('currentDate', new Date().format('yyyy/MM/dd'))
```

You can refer the generated value as `${currentDate}` later on.

See [Date](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html) documentation of [Groovy GDK](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/overview-summary.html) for more information on available functions.

Also be aware that you can achieve the same without having to write even a single line of code via [__time() built-in function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) like:

```
${__time(yyyy/MM/dd,currentDate)}
```

Demo:

[image]